# Let a Virtualbox guest wake up from Suspend

Tags: virtualbox

I prefer to try stuff in a VirtualBox guest before I do it on a physical machine.

In a Linux (Arch Linux to be specific) guest I put the system in suspend mode either by issuing

```
systemctl suspend
```

Or from the host system (my machine is named Arch) by

```
VBoxManage.exe controlvm Arch acpisleepbutton
```

Something happens, I guess it works. The screen goes blank except for a static (non blinking) cursor in the upper left corner.

How do I exit suspend mode? Just typing keys and moving the mouse does not seem to be enough. I looked around but could not find a way to do it from the GUI or `VBoxManage`. Is there a way?

Comment: Good question hehe :)

Answer (score 27):

You can send **ACPI shutdown** with `Host + H` on Windows. Despite the signal name it won't shutdown the guest, it will just wake him up.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm this indeed wakes up the guest machine. (Windows 10 version 1803 host, VirtualBox version 15.2.16, Ubuntu 18.04.1 guest.)